# How to support numpy, scipy in ironpython 2.7.5

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ironpython, enthought

I use the numpy,scipy egg package from https://store.enthought.com/repo/.iron/ and it behave well in ironpython 2.7.3. in Window 7.
But ironpython 2.7.5 support pip install flow so I upgrade to this version but it's ok to import numpy in ironpython.

I find the message as follows:

> > > import numpy
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >            File "", line 1, in 
> > >            File "D:\MyDoc\Training_Course\ISP\IronPython-2.7.5\IronPython-2.7.5\lib\site-
> > >           packages\numpy__init__.py", line 155, in 
> > >            File "D:\MyDoc\Training_Course\ISP\IronPython-2.7.5\IronPython-2.7.5\lib\site-
> > >           packages\numpy\core__init__.py", line 6, in 
> > >            File "D:\MyDoc\Training_Course\ISP\IronPython-2.7.5\IronPython-2.7.5\lib\site-
> > >           packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 7, in 
> > >           ImportError: No module named NumpyDotNet

so I copy IronPython-2.7.5\DLLs*.dll to IronPython-2.7.5 folder and solve the NumpyDotNet module not found issue but one more issue occurs and I list as follows:

```
D:\MyDoc\Training_Course\ISP\IronPython-2.7.5\IronPython-2.7.5>ipy
IronPython 2.7.5 (2.7.5.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.34209 (32-bit)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "D:\MyDoc\Training_Course\ISP\IronPython-2.7.5\IronPython-2.7.5\lib\site-
packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 155, in <module>
 File "D:\MyDoc\Training_Course\ISP\IronPython-2.7.5\IronPython-2.7.5\lib\site-
packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
 File "D:\MyDoc\Training_Course\ISP\IronPython-2.7.5\IronPython-2.7.5\lib\site-
packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 6, in <module>
IOError: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'IronPytho
n, Version=2.7.0.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1' or one of
 its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the
 assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'IronPython, Version=2.7.0.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c
5b713576e1'
 at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, Int
Ptr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInst
Count, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
 at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32
typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] met
hodInstantiationContext)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] ge
nericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
 at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttrib
uteRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, Runtime
Module decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilte
rType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes,
RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters
, Boolean& isVarArg)
 at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decora
tedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFi
lterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecorate
dTargetSecurityTransparent)
 at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly asse
mbly, RuntimeType caType)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType,
Boolean inherit)
 at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType,
 Boolean inherit)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectionUtils.GetCustomAttributes[T](Assembly
assembly, Boolean inherit)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Binding.PythonBinder.DomainManager_AssemblyLoaded(Objec
t sender, AssemblyLoadedEventArgs e)
 at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.ScriptDomainManager.LoadAssembly(Assembly asse
mbly)
 at IronPython.Runtime.ClrModule.AddReference(CodeContext context, Assembly as
sembly)
 at IronPython.Runtime.ClrModule.AddReference(CodeContext context, String name
)
 at IronPython.Runtime.ClrModule.AddReference(CodeContext context, Object refe
rence)
 at IronPython.Runtime.ClrModule.AddReference(CodeContext context, Object[] re
ferences)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFra
me frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0
, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
 at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite s
ite, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame
 frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0
, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
 at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke1Instruction.Run(InterpretedF
rame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
 at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
 at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
 at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleC
ontext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
 at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String mod
uleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, Stri
ng name, String path)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name,
 String fullName, String str)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String
 name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String nam
e, String fullName, List path)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globa
ls, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
 at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Ob
ject globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String f
ullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportTop(CodeContext context, Str
ing fullName, Int32 level)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame
 frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
 at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
 at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
 at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleC
ontext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
 at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String mod
uleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, Stri
ng name, String path)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadPackageFromSource(CodeContext context, Str
ing name, String path)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name,
 String fullName, String str)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String
 name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String nam
e, String fullName, List path)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globa
ls, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
 at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Ob
ject globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String f
ullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportTop(CodeContext context, Str
ing fullName, Int32 level)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame
 frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
 at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
 at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
 at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleC
ontext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
 at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String mod
uleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, Stri
ng name, String path)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadPackageFromSource(CodeContext context, Str
ing name, String path)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name,
 String fullName, String str)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String
 name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String nam
e, String fullName, List path)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String
name)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globa
ls, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
 at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Ob
ject globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame
 frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet
](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String f
ullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
 at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportTop(CodeContext context, Str
ing fullName, Int32 level)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame
 frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 a
rg1)
 at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
 at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
 at IronPython.Hosting.PythonCommandLine.<>c__DisplayClass1.<RunOneInteraction
>b__0()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\M
icrosoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure lo
gging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fus
ion!EnableLog].
```

I ever asked Enthought support, and their response is no plan to upgrade it any more. They suggested me to ask possible support in this forum 
So can anyone have the solution to solve the issue I met ?

Thanks for you in advance.

Comment: you can try pythonnet

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few months but...

You need to enable bind failure logging as described in your error message

> To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\M icrosoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

You will then be able to see where the assembly binding is failing. In my case, there was a publisher policy in GAC redirecting IronPython version to something which did not exist on my system. If so, you'll need to comment it out in the config file.

E.g. in policy.IronPython.config (you'll be able to see the exact file location once you've enabled assembly bind failure logging), comment these two lines out like so:

```
#         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.7.0.40"
#                          newVersion="2.7.5.0"/>
```

Hope it helps.